# Text Field won't populate default date in HTML5 field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, google-chrome, validation

In the HTML5 date input type, Chrome will not put in a default date. The field is rendered empty. Other browsers will have the date, but Chrome has a default date selector that may be causing some of the issues. Any ideas?

`<input type="date" class="input-xlarge" id="date" name="date" 
                    pattern="(0?[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d" value="@Model.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")" required />`

Comment: Does the date populate correctly without the pattern restriction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML5 date value format is yyyy-MM-dd, not MM/dd/yyyy.